# How override Render method from HttpModule?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need override the Render Method of all page, I create a library class and one class than implements IHttpModule, and I put the following code, but doesn´t works. any ideas?

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
        //My code
}
```

(I have searched but have not found an answer yet)

thanks
(Sorry for my english)